# Get Device Total Internal Memory Size

Tags: android, memory, system

I have HTC Device with Internal phone memory size of 16 GB, but the below code only shows 14GB.
I want to find the total internal memory size of the device. Following code only show the internal memory size available to user not the system allotted size.

```
    File path = Environment.getRootDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
    long rootCount=totalBlocks * blockSize;
    Log.e("getRootDirectory",humanReadableByteCount(rootCount,true));

    File dataPath = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs dataStat = new StatFs(dataPath.getPath());
    long dataCount=dataStat.getBlockCountLong() * 
    dataStat.getBlockSizeLong();
    Log.e("getDataDirectory",humanReadableByteCount(dataCount,true));

    File dwnldPath = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory();
    StatFs dwnldStat = new StatFs(dwnldPath.getPath());
    long dwnldCount=dwnldStat.getBlockCountLong() * 
    dwnldStat.getBlockSizeLong();

         /*
    File extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs extStat = new StatFs(extPath.getPath());
    long extCount=extStat.getBlockCountLong() * 
   extStat.getBlockSizeLong();

    */
    long total=rootCount+dataCount+dwnldCount;
```

Anyone knows how to find exact internal memory size of the device(phone internal memory size+ system area size)

Comment: maybe I think it counts free space

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258998/get-internal-and-external-memory-size-in-marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

try this way to find memory

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

Comment: @JyotiManhas see this link https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-get-android-ram-internal-and-external-memory-information/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code you are getting internal, external as well as ram memories:

```
public static boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}

public static String getAvailableInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
}

public static String getTotalInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
}

public static String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
}

public static String getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
        return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
}

public static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = "KB";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "MB";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder resultBuffer = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

    int commaOffset = resultBuffer.length() - 3;
    while (commaOffset > 0) {
        resultBuffer.insert(commaOffset, ',');
        commaOffset -= 3;
    }

    if (suffix != null) resultBuffer.append(suffix);
    return resultBuffer.toString();
}
```

Get RAM Size

```
ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem;
```

Comment: Not worked, i need to find the method to access the system memory file

Comment: you want ram size?

Comment: kindly check my edited question for more clarification.

Comment: I want device total internal memory size which is shown in the settings screen under storage option.

Comment: @JyotiManhas I don't think android provide whole internal memory size.

Comment: storage space app is showing the internal memory correctly